# Multiplying float with BigInt in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multiplication, biginteger, bigint

[By using this website](https://www.calculator.net/big-number-calculator.html)

I can calculate for example

```
x = 0.28
y = 1e18
x * y = 280,000,000,000,000,000
```

How can I do this in javascript while x could be any number, including ints, and y could be any other big number like 1e12 or whatever.

Comment: `BigInt` cannot be  mixed with other types. What is the result you expect?

Comment: I expecte to get the same result as the website i linked

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix BigInt with other types in a calculation, so you need to use BigInt for all the operands.

So instead of multiplying the float by `0.28`, multiply by `28n` and divide by `100n`.

```
console.log((BigInt(1e18) * 28n) / 100n)
```

Comment: As I said, the numbers can be unknown at runtime

Comment: You need to require the input to be supplied in this form. If 0.28 represents a percentage, ask for the percentage rather than a fraction, so they enter `28` and you do the division by 100 in your code.

Comment: Or count the number of digits after the decimal point, then scale up. If they enter `.285`, use `BigInt(Math.round(input*1000))` to convert it, then divide by `1000n`.